# How to Use Feather Icons on Laravel through Laravel Mix, NPM

Tags: npm, icons, laravel-mix

I am trying to use feather icons in laravel enviroment, I thought i would do it through npm. Can someone help me understand how this work as I couldnt get it working. I am very new to working with packages.

I installed

```
npm install feather-icons --save
```

then I added `const feather = require('feather-icons')` to my resource/app.js,

then I run "npm run dev"

1. How would i display the icons listed at this website (say cirlce) on my pages?
2. Is what I did above correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes what you did is correct. Follow the steps for adding icon to your project.

1. Add `feather.replace()` method in same `app.js` file.
2. Link generated file to your layout or page it should be stored in `public/js` by default so the script tag is looks like (assuming you using it in Laravel Blade)

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Or if you are using Laravel Mix

```html
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

3. Add desired icon to your markup

```html
<h1><i data-feather="circle"></i>Hello World</h1>
```

it should work fine. alternatively you can use directly by linking to CDN.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>
  <body>

    <!-- example icon -->
    <i data-feather="circle"></i>

    <script>
      feather.replace()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,it seems I was missing `feather.replace()`. It is working now. Can you help me with reducing the size to font size? How can i do that?

Comment: Your welcome. I don't get it what do you mean reduce the size to font size? Do you want to reduce the fonts size?

Comment: I mean how can I reduce the size of the icon? It's bit too big.

Comment: If your intention is width & height you can set it via CSS but if you mean file size the core script is approximately 16.5 KB and you should not worry about it.
for CSS you use `.feather` class with `width` `height` properties.

Comment: I was able to change the size with CSS, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey there, I have one more question. Do you know a way to use the icons in my app.scss file? I am trying to change one of my <ul> to have a feather icon as list-style-image? I guess I can put all icons in my public view and point it to it. Is it possible for me to that without the putting all icons in my public folder?

Comment: As far as i know you should use public which is a standard way to use an asset because we **can't** reference node_module folder like so `list-style-image: url('~feather-icons/icons/circle.svg');` (though it would be great if there is a way.)

Answer (score 2):

```
1.resource/assets/js/app.js
=================================
2.paste this code 
=================================

 require('./bootstrap');
//integrate
 const feather = require('feather-icons')
//call
 feather.replace();

============================================
3.write on terminal
============================================
npm install feather-icons
npm run dev

=======================================
4.in blade file
=======================================
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title></title>

  <body>

    <!-- example icon -->
    <i data-feather="circle"></i>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 10 you need to add these 2 lines inside resources/js/app.js

```
import feather from 'feather-icons';
feather.replace();
```

After that just run

```
npm run build
```